# How to properly extend Entity Query class?

Tags: entities, 9

I am working on some complex aggregate reporting that pulls from several sources (node type) and generates a report in a table display. There are about 10ish line items (could be more later) and methods all have a common query:

```
    $query = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')
      ->getQuery()
      ->condition('type', 'offer')
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->condition('field_status_list', self::STATUS_ACTIVE)
      ->condition('field_plan_type_edc', [1,2,3], 'IN')
      ->condition('field_customer_class', [1,2,3], 'IN')
```

Other line items may add a line or two to that, like:

```
$query->condition('field_fees', [1,2,3], 'IN');
```

If I wanted to separate this out into its own class instead of have it mixed into the controller, how would I extend the Query class? I assume I need a fresh instance of a Query object for each line item I want to calculate and aggregate (or it would have previous conditions applied I do not want). Then I could just call a method like this:

```
  public function hasFee(string $fee_type) {
    $this->condition('field_fees', [array_search($fee_type, [1,2,3])], 'IN');
    return $this;
  }
```

that builds upon the base query above, so the userland code would look more like:

```
$this->myQueryService->getQuery()->hasFee('name')->execute();
```

instead of repeat `$this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')..` over and over. It would also make this usable outside of this specific controller class.

Comment: an option, you can use addMetadata + addTag and in hook query tag alter to process logic.

Comment: Adding a custom query extender (like 'pager', 'table_sort', etc) is another option

Comment: What would those look like?

Comment: Actually I think I'm wrong, looks like extenders are for select queries only, not entity queries

Comment: Extending the storage class is tricky in this case because you're working with nodes, so you would have to change the storage class for all nodes and then have conditional logic in your extended class to handle nodes of your specific type. An alternative would be to create a service that has the storage class injected and let the service take care of performing all the entity queries.

Comment: You can extend the node storage class with a function `getFeeQuery`. Than you can call `$this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->getFeeQuery()` and get always your base query object.
It is also possible to create your own service or to extend the Node Query with a function like `hasFee('name')`.